# Error using renderToString in React.js to enable server-side rendering using express

Tags: reactjs, express, babeljs, server-side-rendering

This is my server/server.js:

```
import express from "express";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer, { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

import App from '../src/App';

const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./build', {index: false}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        const reactApp = renderToString(
            <App/>
            //<h2>Works using a simple h2</h2>
        );

        return res.send(
            `
            <html>
                <body>
                    <div id="root">${reactApp}</div>
                </body>
            </html>
            `
        );
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

My server/index.js:

```
// server/index.js
require("ignore-styles");

require("@babel/register")({
  ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
});

require("./server");
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';

function App () {
  return (
     <div className="App">
       <Home/>
     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Finally, after I run the command:

`node server/index.js`

I got this **error**:

*Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
*

Answer (score 1):

in your server file, change the import to be

```js
import App from '../src/App';  // good
```

instead of

```js
import {App} from '../src/App';  // bad
```

Because your App component is a default export, i.e. `export default App`, and not a named export, i.e. `export { App }`

Comment: Now I got this error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: can you share a reproduction sandbox?

Comment: Example SandBox: 
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/6zzlk3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A10%2C5

Comment: I think the problem is about .tsx files
Because it works with .js files